# Compile time checking of constness

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, compile-time, compile-time-constant

If I have a function

```
int calcStuff_dynamic(const int a, const int b)
```

and some template meta code

```
template<int a, int b>
struct calcStuff_static {
    static const int value = //some more code
};
```

Is there a way to write a wrapper

```
int calcStuff(const int a, const int b) {
    IF_THESE_ARE_KNOWN_CONSTANTS_AT_COMPILE_TIME(a, b)
        return calcStuff_static<a, b>::value;
    ELSE_TEMPLATE_WOULD_FAIL
        return calcStuff_dynamic(a, b);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "IF_THESE_ARE_KNOWN" ?

Comment: Do you use a different algorithm in the static case than in the non-static case? Why? Otherwise, you are looking for `constexpr`.

Comment: See [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

Comment: `a` and `b` in `calcStuff` are not constant expressions so they cannot be used as template arguments in `calcStuff_dynamic`.

Comment: @quantdev I'll change it, but I mean known constants at compile time. If they weren't the template would fail.

Comment: @juanchopanza Looks interesting. But if I wanted to use it on Arduino, is there a non-C++11 method?

Comment: @0x499602D2 If `a` and `b` are known constants when `calcStuff` is called, why can't the compiler carry them through?

Comment: C++11 has the is_const type trait. I don't know if you might be able to convert that to C++03. I don't know why devices and such still views C++11 as black magic.

Comment: @Mads I'd love to be able to use C++11 everywhere. I saw avr-g++ was built on gcc 4.3 so I assumed it was too old. But I just ran it with the `--std=c++11` switch and it didn't barf. I'll have to figure out how to make that used by default. EDIT. Never mind, doesn't work...

Comment: gcc 4.3 is so old it doesn't even barf when you give it meaningless compilation flags :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it, but it will be done by smart compilers.

Maybe first solution that comes to the mind is to use *SFINAE* in combination of *constexpr* values. In this case we need something to detect *constexpr* values.

But, there is no `is_constexpr` or something similar to detect values that are known in compile time. On the other hand, the function `is_const` is not useful because `constexpr` is not part of a type. So, you can not do that (or at least I don't know a straight solution).

However you will be glad if you know that there is an optimization is many compilers which computes the final value of a function for known values in compile time. For example in GCC, there is *"SCEV final value replacement"*.

Therefore you should just use that dynamic function when the parameters are unknown and the compiler will do it as your wish (If it is possible).

Comment: Oh cool. Does SCEV make some of the uses of metaprogramming moot?

Comment: When I looked at the assembly for a `gcd(3432,gcd(231,2312))` on avr-g++-4.3 I saw that it wasn't unrolled. Is this a newer feature of g++?

Answer (score 0):

GCC, Clang and the Intel compiler all support [__builtin_constant_p](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~pad/tigcc/doc/tigcclib/gnuexts_SEC104___builtin_constant_p.html) to check whether the value is a compile-time constant and to provide an optimized expression in that case.

For all other compilers, you can use the dynamic computation as a fallback. (I'm not aware that there is an equivalent for Visual Studio.)

Comment: Thank you. It actually doesn't work in this case:
`int calcStuff(const int a, const in b) {
    return __builtin_constant_p(a) && __builtin_constant_p(b) ? calcStuff_static<a,b>::value : calcStuff_dynamic(a,b);
}`

Comment: @user315118 Does it work if you express `a && b ? expr1 : expr2` as `a ? (b ? expr1 : expr2) : expr2`?